# json api account search in php

Tags: php, json, api

I have small problem with my project. I don't know much, because 
I'm only learning now PHP arrays, I want to create some like this

```
PewDiePie
PewDiePie1
PewDiePie2
```

and on click `href` to account_id.

Here is PHP code:

```
$link = $_GET['search'];
$str_data = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/list/?application_id=ID_OF_APPLICATION&search=$link");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);

function echo_array($a, $key){
    foreach($a as $key1 => $array1){
        if(!is_array($array1)){
            echo "$key $key1 : $array1 </br>";
        }else{
            echo_array($array1,"$key $key1");
        }
    }
}
echo_array($data,'');
```

This is output of PHP file

> **status : ok
>  meta count : 100
>  data 0 nickname : Pewdiepie
>  data 0 account_id : 501337127
>  data 1 nickname : Pewdiepie00 
>
>   data 1 account_id : 510468398 
>  data 2 nickname : pewdiepie007 
>
>   data 2 account_id :511343434**

but I want to make only some like **$nickname** and **$account_id**, but when I tried, it was been a fail.
Will you advise me?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow, can you explain what result do you want ?

Comment: @Jonathan Delean Thank you, i want some php page using json (API) to search players, when you type exc.: PewDiePie ,  i want result all profiles with name PewDiePie, no:  data 0 nickname : Pewdiepie , i only want Pewdiepie, and on click on name <a> attribute will redirect by ACCOUNT_ID to next page player.php?id=501337127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function need to be :

```
function echo_array($a, $key){
    foreach($a['data'] as $data){
            echo $data['nickname'];
            echo $data['account_id'];
    }
}
```

If you post the Json result, i can more explain how acces to the children node

Comment: I tried, but no output :/. This is json result from worldoftanks website : {"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"data":[{"nickname":"pewdiepie007","account_id":511343434}]}

Comment: `<form method="get" id="search" action="index.php?search=">
 <span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nick" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn"  />
 </span>
</form>
<?php
$link = $_GET['search'];
$str_data = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/list/?application_id=#&search=$link");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);

function echo_array($a, $key){
    foreach($a['data'] as $data){
            echo $data['nickname'];
            echo $data['account_id'];
    }
}
?>
` still not working :/

Comment: Nothing prompt ? try to just echo $data and give me the result please

Answer (score 0):

Okey i have solution, because in code is 2 same arrays

```
$link = $_GET['search'];
$str_data = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/list/?application_id=#&search=$link");
//there is data $data = json_decode($str_data,true);

function echo_array($a, $key){
    foreach($a['data'] as $data1){
          //and there is data  echo $data['nickname'];
            echo $data['account_id'];
    }
}
echo_array($data,'');
```

i changed to

```
$link = $_GET['search'];
$str_data = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/list/?application_id=#&search=$link");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);

function echo_array($a, $key){
    foreach($a['data'] as $data1){
            echo $data1['nickname'];
            echo $data1['account_id'];
    }
}
echo_array($data,'');
```

and now is working, Thank you Jonathan, have a nice day :)

Comment: It's exacly what i said you, perfect, valide my answer to close the post